# TPlane versus TImage3D?

Tags: delphi, 3d, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have an DelphiXE4 application made with **FMX**.

I want to have **flat textured objects (no thickness) where I can zoom and move the whole scene on the screen**.
(hint : Think about pictures on a wall)

I started with a TForm3D to implement `TImage3D` components with bitmap assigned. It works well!
BUT I've tested with the `TPlane` component, I can do the same thing and achieve the same result.

The question is : **What is the difference between these 2 components `TImage3D` & `TPlane` ?**
This will help me to choose the right one for my - current and further - needs.
FMX documents and wiki doesn't really help here !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to think about these things is to look at the inheritance path.

`TImage3D` derives from `TAbstractLayer` and so it can generally be used like a 3D layer. `TAbstractLayer` derives from `TControl3D` but also implements `IAlignableObject` and `IAlignRoot`.

`TPlane` derives from `TCustomMesh` which derives from `TShape3D` which also comes from `TControl3D`.

I guess in brief a `TPlane` is simply a specific 3D shape - I haven't poured through the FMX source code but I would guess that it must be more lightweight than `TImage3D`.  A `TPlane` is just a flat surface that can be manipulated in 3D space.

A `TImage3D`, however, by means of `IAlignableObject`, etc, has access to a number of built-in methods and features that allow it to interact as a 3D UI object - to align itself to other `IAlignableObjects`, to define margins, bounds, and anchors, etc, to define how it places itself in, or fills, space with respect to other `IAlignableObjects`.

Which to use depends on what you are doing.  If you want the image to be a part of a 3D scene, then `TPlane` probably makes most sense.  If you want it to be part of a 3D UI; that is to say that the image is part of a 3D space with other controls, user-interface elements, etc, then `TImage3D` probably makes most sense.

A `TImage3D` may not have access, at the same time, to certain methods that operate on `TCustomMesh` - a TImage probably doesn't expose its mesh (ie: can't be generically modified by 3D transforms, etc, where the input must be a `TCustomMesh`), while a `TPlane`, being a 3D primitive rather than a locked-down UI control, would be rather more malleable in that regard.

Comment: Another difference I've seen is about bitmap : `TImage3D` have an embedded Bitmap, `TPlane` is link to a MaterialSource (with a texture, that is a bitmap).
But I think there is no big difference on this point.